# Windows 10 UWP Two Adaptive Triggers not working as expected

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have this VisualStateGroups for different screen resolutions. If I resize the window from small to large everything is working as expected. However If I resize the window from large to small the first Visual State Group got ignored and the windows layout is jumping back to the one defined at the controls itself.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualState>
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <!--VisualState to be triggered when window width is >= ??? effective pixels.-->
            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"></AdaptiveTrigger>
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelAmount"/>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelRate"/>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelRemainingTime"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelAmount"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
<VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualState>
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <!--VisualState to be triggered when window width is >= ??? effective pixels.-->
            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="900"></AdaptiveTrigger>
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelAmount"/>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelRate"/>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
            <Setter Target="labelRemainingTime.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelFee"/>
            <Setter Target="labelRemainingTime.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelRate"/>
            <Setter Target="labelRemainingTime.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelRemainingTime"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelRate"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Folks I found it out myself. The Triggers need to be in the same VisualStateGroup Element to work like I want it to.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualState>
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <!--VisualState to be triggered when window width is >= ??? effective pixels.-->
            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"></AdaptiveTrigger>
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelAmount"/>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelRate"/>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelRemainingTime"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelAmount"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState>
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <!--VisualState to be triggered when window width is >= ??? effective pixels.-->
            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="900"></AdaptiveTrigger>
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelAmount"/>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelRate"/>
            <Setter Target="labelFee.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
            <Setter Target="labelRemainingTime.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelFee"/>
            <Setter Target="labelRemainingTime.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelRate"/>
            <Setter Target="labelRemainingTime.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="labelRemainingTime"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="labelRate"/>
            <Setter Target="labelLendingDate.Margin" Value="10,3,3,0"/>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```